# Single NIC board and a switch as router

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, switch

I was wondering if it is possible to setup a single NIC computer as a router. This is for a home setup.

I would like to have something like this:

```
         [ Single NIC computer ]
                   |
                   |
[ DOCSIS ] --- [ switch1 ] ------- [ host1 ]  
                |  |  | ---------- [ host2 ]  
                |  | ------------- [ host3 ]  
                |
               [ switch2 ]
                |  |  |
```

This could be summed as "Using a raspberry pi and a switch as a router" ( It's not a pi, but it runs linux ). I would like to know if such a setup can possibly work and what I should look for to make it work. At this point, general technologies involved I should look into would be an ok answer.

My initial guess is that it will require a lot of tweaking on each host to make sure DHCP requests do not end up answered by the DOCSIS modem. I think that if the router successfully answer DHCP requests for hosts, then routes will be managed properly, but I have a strong hunch that it might be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that if you use a switch with VLAN support. (Sometimes called a managed switch).

On the switch you configure two VLANs. One VLAN contains the port connected to the modem. Another VLAN contains all the host ports. All of those ports should be configured as untagged.

You configure the switch port connected to the router to have both VLANs. At least one of the two VLANs on that port will need to be tagged on that port. You could choose to tag both.

On your router you will by default see a single network interface connected to the untagged VLAN on the port. That network interface might be named `eth0`, but depending on exact OS version installed it may be named differently.

You can use `vconfig` to create a virtual interface connected to a tagged VLAN. For example if you want an interface connected to tag 2, you could type:

```
vconfig add eth0 2
```

This will create a virtual interface called `eth0.2`.

Only `switch1` in your diagram will need VLAN support. `switch2` can be an unmanaged switch. If you wanted modem and router connected to different switches you need VLAN tagging on the entire path between router and modem, and all the switches on that path will need to have VLAN support.

Comment: if I understand correctly, the managed switch will allow me to say "port1 and port2 in a virtual segment" and "all other ports are in another segment". Is that correct?

Comment: With the additional feature that I'm looking for to include the "router" port in 2 different segments

Comment: @Eric Yes the managed switch will allow you to separate the ports into virtual segments. And using tagging it can allow selected ports to be part of more than one segment.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll mark you as accepted, but do you think there is a solution that could work with a "normal" switch?

Comment: @Eric DOCSIS modems can be configured to only accept a small number of MAC addresses. If configured to say only accept 4 MAC addresses it will only talk to the first 4 MAC addresses it sees after booting. After that it will ignore all other MAC addresses. If your ISP has configured that limit as 1 and the modem always sees the router first, and the router has been configured to ignore its own DHCP requests, it could work. But it would be a fragile setup prone to break every time the modem restarts.